# Restoring .bk file to postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I was provided with a .bk file that I need to restore on a postgreSQL DB.

[Reference for Restoring DB](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-restore-database/)

I used the following command-line from the link above : `psql -d EneFrame -U username -f backupfile.bk`

After asking for the password, it seems to do some `copying of rows`, `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE INDEX` and at the end `REVOKE` and `GRANT` - However, in the beginning I get the following errors, but still seems to run and finish... :

[image]

Then when I open pgAdmin - I dont see any change in the DB I am trying to restore to ?

I just started with postgreSQL today, so dont know much. Am I trying to restore incorrectly ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Server is trying to use a role named `dbu` and it's not created. This is probably for setting some access rights. Seeing the first 43 rows of your file could give some hint. Or ask the person who gave you the file should there be such user created first. Or you could just type `CREATE ROLE dbu;` to psql prompt before loading your file.

Comment: Interesting - I thought this was something to do with the postgreSQL server. It seems you may have been right. I still dont know what dbu is, so will need to check with the person that sent it to me. I see the Tables are under Schemas(1) >> public >> Tables. I expected it to be similar to MSSQL, and directly under the DBName. Thanks a mill!!